# How do I delete a file whose name begins with "-" (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?

Tags: shell, command-line, rm, quoting, options

How do you remove a file whose filename begins with a dash (hyphen or minus) `-`?  I'm ssh'd into a remote OSX server and I have this file in my directory:

```
tohru:~ $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 me  staff  1352 Aug 18 14:33 --help
...
```

How in the world can I delete `--help` from a CLI?  This issue is something that I come across in different forms on occasion, these files are easy to create, but hard to get rid of.

I have tried using backslash

```
rm \-\-help
```

I have tried quotes

```
rm "--help"
```

How do I prevent the minus (dash or hyphen) character to be interpreted as an option?

Comment: Would be great if this question was renamed to "How to delete a file whose name starts with --".

Comment: @Sandy Agreed; I normally dislike changing a question's meaning, but in this case the accepted answer is specific to this problem

Comment: i find it a bit ironic that `rm --help` actually explains how to delete filenames beginning with a `-`. good question nevertheless.

Comment: @lesmana irony indeed :D.  I think there is a good lesson to be learned here (read the help - it may indeed be helpful).

Comment: @jw013 Sometimes the help is easy for experienced users to understand, but overwhelming and confusing to newbs.

Comment: I ran into this on a system using rm from BusyBox. Everything is minimal, including the help, so rm --help did not provide any clues.

Comment: Same on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706196/how-to-remove-files-starting-with-double-hyphen) and [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/47003/deleting-a-unix-directory-with-a-hyphen-in-the-name).

Comment: Ironically, `--help` isn't always helpful. OS X: `rm --help` returns `rm: illegal option -- -` and `usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...`. BusyBox returns `Usage: rm [-irf] FILE...`. The `rm -- $file` trick is mentioned in the man page on OS X, but most embedded systems don't bother installing the man pages.

Comment: Achievement unlocked: How did we get here

Answer (score 731, accepted):

Use "--" to make rm stop parsing command line options, like this:

```
rm -- --help
```

Comment: Do all versions of the `rm` command support the `--` argument?

Comment: @KeithThompson -- is a feature of most GNU tools, so it won't work on most non-GNU ("non-Linux") Unix'es (e.g. BSD variants or some embedded systems)

Comment: THANKS! That saved my day. And of course it works on BSD (OSX) and with other commands!

Comment: It works with IBM AIX's old school System V UNIX coreutils. It is safe to say it will work _anywhere_.

Comment: @dtech, getopt() and `--` predate GNU (SysIII, 1980) and are standard/POSIX. Standard utilities except for a few exceptions (like `echo`) understand `--`. YMMV for other commands if they don't use the getopt() API to parse options.

Comment: It works on the rm that's included with BusyBox, found on IoT devices (Raspberry Pi, Intel Edison, etc), Android phones, tablets, and other devices like Amazon Fire and even hacked Wii systems.

Comment: Is there any downside to always using `rm [options] -- [file]` in environments that allow it?

Answer (score 299):

Or you can do

```
rm ./--help
```

Comment: This is the one that I remember. Using "rm -- --help" is something I always have to look up.

Comment: This method always works even for commands that don't treat `--` specially.

Comment: And it also works to avoid special treatment by some commands for other types (beside options) of specially named arguments like the `-` of text utilities or `cd`, the `foo=bar` of `awk`...

Comment: This works when a file begins with a single dash, where `rm -- <filename>` did not.

Comment: Nice solution, help also with: mv ./--help /tmp/

Comment: Yes I usually use this method.

Comment: This should be the answer because it works for other commands as well.

Comment: I prefer this method. 'Tis more intuitive

Answer (score 48):

Use `find` to do it:

```
find . -name '--help' -delete
```

And this is a good method because if you have more then a few files like this that you can delete you can get a preview list of the files by simply running find without the `-delete` option first, and then if the list of files look good just run it again with `-delete`.

In fact, you avoiding `rm` in favor of `find` (especially with preview first) is a good habit that will help you avoid mistakes with `rm *` that will inevitably bite you some day.

Note, though, that find will recurse through all your subdirectories, so you might want to run it with a subdirectory depth constraint like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '--help' -delete
```

which limits the find to the current directory.

Comment: Portably, you need to give `find` a list of files/dirs to look into. So `find . -name...`. `-delete` and `-maxdepth` are not standard options either.

Answer (score 20):

The answers of Vegar Nilsen and edfuh are very good and the proper solutions to a problem like this.

I do want to add a general response to this question that allows you to delete *any* file with a difficult file name. First its inode number is obtained using `ls -i` or some form of `stat` and then the file is removed by searching for files in the current directory by inode number and executing the `rm` command on the file or files with a matching inode number:

```
find . -inum <inode> -exec rm -- {} \;
```

Since inode numbers are unique in each file system you can remove any file using this; unicode or using escape characters. It is how ever very annoying to type out so I would recommend adding the line

```
TAB: menu-complete             # Tab: Cycles through the command
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward # Shift-Tab: Cycles backwards
```

into your `.inputrc` file if you're using bash. This allows you to cycle through the list of possible completions ([for further information](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC19)).

Comment: This way has two problems: 1) do not use -exec rm when you can use -delete; 2) obtaining the inode and using that is needlessly overcomplicated when you can just use: `find -name '--help' -delete`

Comment: I don't think that will work.  It traverses all the files in the current directory and all its subdirectories, and after all that it *still* invokes `rm --help`, which still won't remove the file.  Just use `rm ./--help` (or `rm -i *`.

Comment: @KeithThompson `find` prefixes the command line argument path to all files, so it would run `rm ./--help` and `rm ./sub/dirs/--help`.  To fix the second, one would have to add `-maxdepth 1`, but all of this is essentially applying @edfuh's solution in a more roundabout, convoluted way, and `-delete` is safer than `-exec rm` anyways.

Comment: One more issue with this command is that there must be a space between `{}` and `\;`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: _inodes_ may be unique but there may be several directory entries with the same inode. Those are called hardlinks. And they're only unique per file system, so you'd need to use `-xdev`. That won't help you to run that `ls -i --help`.

Comment: sigh, first, it's `-inum` and not `-inode` in at least the GNU and FreeBSD versions of find; second, `-inum` isn't magic, the file still gets passed by name to `rm` or `unlink()`, though here, using `.` as the start point will cause `rm` to get the filename `./-foo`, bypassing the problem; third, you need a space between `{}` and `\;`.

Answer (score 11):

A brutal solution:

```
perl -e "unlink '--help' or die 'Could not unlink.';"

perl -e "rmdir '-d' or die 'Could not rmdir.';"
```

Answer (score 8):

**Linux Walkthrough of creating a file with dashes and spaces, then removing it.**

BE CAREFUL!  Don't accidentally run a `rm -rf /` or similar cascade delete command.

If your file you are trying to remove includes asterisks or slashes, do not accidentally pump a `.` or `/*` or `*` or some other wildcard which could cascade delete your operating system.

**Create a file called "--yo yo"**

```
eric@dev ~ $ touch -- "--yo yo"
eric@dev ~ $ ls
bin  --yo yo
```

**First, find it with find:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ find . -name "*--yo yo*"
./--yo yo
```

Make sure the find command ONLY finds the ONE file you want to delete:

**Then pass the -delete option to find, to delete them:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ find . -name "*--yo yo*" -delete
eric@dev ~ $ ls
bin
```

Aaaannd it's gone.

Answer (score 2):

Midnight Commander (`mc`) is the easiest, just point at it and hit F8 ;)

Comment: The OP wants a command line (CLI) solution.

Comment: Midnight Commander IS a CLI solution. Just use your package manger to install it. (It even works over ssh...) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander

Comment: How is `apt-get install mc || yum install mc; mc` *various arrow keys and F8* easier than `rm ./--help`?

Comment: @daviewales: Midnight Commander is *started* from the command line, and it *runs* in the terminal, but all keyboard actions within Midnight Commander are not from the CLI  (Command Line Interface) - they are from Midnight Commander's Interface. - Typically, command line utilities can be run within a script (an exception is bash command line history)

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution that i had used before finding this thread.
use `vim` to 'edit' directory:

```
vim .
```

then (in vim) select your file, hit del and confirm deletion.
when you're done quit vim with `:q`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add the directory name as prefix:

```
$ rm ./-filename.txt dirname/-filename2.txt
$ mv ./-filename.txt filename.txt
$ cp teste ./-teste
```

Using the directory as prefix of the file in general helps avoiding the wrongly interpretation of the "minus" character as a command option by the parser function.

Comment: I believe this was already covered [in an earlier answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1529/116858).

Answer (score -4):

If you want to rename the file, `-.bar`, (mv won't work), try this:

```
cat >foo.bar <-.bar
```

before using the command:

```
rm -- -.bar
```

You should be able to examine the original file's contents in foo.bar

Comment: Making a copy of the file is not a very efficient solution for renaming it.

Comment: You could use vidir; but that is probably just as (or even more) inefficient - and much more dangerous.