# How can I grep through files whose name begins with `-`?

Tags: text-processing, grep, filenames

I've tried this.

```
grep -r thanks *                                      slave-iv
grep: invalid option -- '@'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Here's what the directory looks like. They're log files from pidgin.

```
ls -1
-100000139702926@chat.facebook.com
-100001138571192@chat.facebook.com
-1021869012@chat.facebook.com
-12120618@chat.facebook.com
-1251570038@chat.facebook.com
-1269333626@chat.facebook.com
-1394365872@chat.facebook.com
-1657581332@chat.facebook.com
-211203163@chat.facebook.com
-505152641@chat.facebook.com
-549333601@chat.facebook.com
-557177029@chat.facebook.com
-573222477@chat.facebook.com
-584051302@chat.facebook.com
-65000319@chat.facebook.com
-663869224@chat.facebook.com
-664953132@chat.facebook.com
-755682783@chat.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh! I just realized after asking my problem is not the `@` it's the `-` this works

```
grep -r thanks -- *
```

Comment: [More info](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with)

Comment: @Michael: Isn't this is one more exact duplicate?