# Error with grep and find

Tags: grep, find, special-characters

When I try to execute :

```
$ man find | grep "-mtime"
```

I get this message back :

```
grep: invalid max count
```

I wonder how to search with the **-**

Comment: try with: man find | grep "\-mtime"

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87355/ ,  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364922/ .

Comment: if you are often extracting option description from man pages, I would suggest https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+-mtime or a bash script I wrote(https://github.com/learnbyexample/command_help) for use from cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Fólkvangr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/286944/f%c3%b3lkvangr) commented, the problem is that your pattern starts with a `-` character.

To avoid that grep will try to use the pattern as a parameter, you have to use the `-e` parameter before the pattern.

```
$ man find | grep -e "-mtime"
```

From `man grep`

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>
> Use PATTERN as the pattern.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the -f (--file)  option,  search  for  all  patterns given.  **This option can be used to protect a pattern beginning with “-”**.

Comment: The `-f` option from `grep` takes a filename as parameter that contains patterns.