# Handling an option-like filename in the shell

Tags: command-line, options

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a file whose name begins with "--"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with)

Due to mismatched switches when I was trying to run a command, I have a log file named `-w` in a directory. I want to see its contents with `cat` (or `less`) and then delete it.

I've tried escaping it with backslashes, single-quotes, double-quotes, parentheses, and backticks, but `cat` always complains that `w` is an unknown option.

How can I properly reference this file?

Comment: I would merge, but all the answers are already on the other question

Comment: @Michael: The other thread is much less concise than this one. The redirection should have been the other way around :-p

Comment: @Stephane Typically you close newer questions as duplicates of older ones, unless the older one was completely terrible

Answer (score 6):

Almost all commands allow `--` as separator between options parameters and positional parameters. You can use the following:

```
cat -- -w
rm -f -- -w
```

Answer (score 4):

Prefix it with the path. For instance:

```
cat /home/whatever/-w
rm /home/whatever/-w
```

Comment: Nice trick that works when parameters are filenames. One may use `./-w` also.

Comment: @Stéphane: right, `./` also suffices!