# Why doesn't "rm *" work when there are files that begin with a hyphen?

Tags: bash, wildcards, rm

from: http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2011/Sep/190

```
[USER@MACHINE ~] mkdir ejha
[USER@MACHINE ~] cd ejha/
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] touch ize
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] touch -- -f -i
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 USER USER 0 Sep 20 19:44 -f
-rw-rw-r--. 1 USER USER 0 Sep 20 19:44 -i
-rw-rw-r--. 1 USER USER 0 Sep 20 19:44 ize
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] rm *
rm: remove regular empty file `ize'? y
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 USER USER 0 Sep 20 19:44 -f
-rw-rw-r--. 1 USER USER 0 Sep 20 19:44 -i
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha]
```

infos about the system:

```
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
Release:    14
Codename:   Laughlin
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha] rpm -qa | fgrep bash
bash-4.1.7-4.fc14.i686
[USER@MACHINE ~/ejha]
```

Why? Why doesn't it deletes the "-f" and "-i" file?

Comment: This is very similar to [How do I delete a file whose name begins with "-" (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus)

Comment: And to [Handling an option-like filename in the shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18634/handling-an-option-like-filename-in-the-shell/18635)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It isn't deleting them because it recognises the filenames as arguments (unquoted, in this situation `*` expands to `-f -i ize`). To delete these files, either do `rm -- *`, or `rm ./*`. `--` signifies the end of arguments, `./` uses the link to the current directory to circumvent `rm`'s argument detection.

Generally `./*` is preferable, as some programs do not accept `--` to stop checking for arguments.

This is not a bug. This is something that should be handled by calling `rm` in the correct fashion to avoid such issues.

Comment: *"as some programs do not accept `--` to stop checking for arguments"* and other programs except a single dash for that purpose.

Comment: @dmckee *some* other programs do, not all.

Comment: It's not a bug, you're right.  But I would call it a design flaw, as it shows the fragility of shells not distinguishing between things that should be taken literally (filenames) and things that should be interpreted (switches).  The way most programming languages work (string literals are in quotes, everything else is interpreted) seems to be a much better design.  Of course you can always use quotes, but Unix shells were not *designed* around the idea that we'd always use quotes.  Quite the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a bit of clarity, the "*" is being expanded by your shell, not by 'rm', so the 'rm' command just gets the list of files as arguments.  So in your example 'rm *' is exactly equivalent to typing 'rm -f -i ize'.

In other systems (e.g., the Windows/DOS command line) the "*" gets expanded to a list of files by the command itself, so the command 'knows' all matching files are files.  The downside of that approach is that each command needs to implement the globbing and re-implement globbing configuration and quoting rules, etc.

Comment: "The downside of that approach is that each command needs to implement the globbing and re-implement globbing configuration and quoting rules, etc." well, it could be part of a library. It's really a historical artifact that UNIX didn't have the ability to share anything except the kernel, so it was better to have it in one _process_ rather than in a library linked by each program. Whereas, in DOS, this was part of the "library/kernel blob" that was the DOS interrupt handlers.