# Accidently created a file called -X, how can I delete it?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus)

Like an idiot, I ran this command:

```
    tar -cf -X awstats-icon icon tarfile.tar .
```

I was trying to use the -X switch to exclude awstats-icon and icon directories.

Now I have a large file named -X and I cannot seem to delete it. I tried using:

```
    rm -X
    rm `-X`
    rm '-X'
```

However none of these have worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Like an idiot, I ran this command: ...` you're not an idiot, it's just that `tar` is old-fashioned.

Answer (score 43):

Try `rm ./-X` from the folder that "-X" resides in.

Comment: This solution will work even when the individual command doesn't support the `--` trick.

Answer (score 40):

You can use `--` on a shell command to make it clear that options have ended, this should therefore work:
`rm -- -X`

Comment: Good answer, but readers should note that `--` is only supported by the GNU tools. Don't expect it to work on BSD.

Comment: To reiterate what Zan said, `--` is not a shell feature, it's a feature of `rm` and many other GNU tools. Not all tools support it, so Tim's answer is more portable, across Unix systems and across utilities.