# How to rename multiple files by removing the extension?

Tags: rename

I have a number of tiff files named:

```
sw.001.tif
sw.002.tif
...
```

and I want to remove the `.tif` at the end of each of the files.  How can I use the `rename` command to do this?

Comment: Bear in mind that NO linux or unix filesystem uses Windows or VMS-style "extensions" - it is only by convention that a suffix of the file name is ".tif" or ".c" or ".o" or ".so" or whatever.

Comment: That's fine... I'm importing files from windows to linux :)

Comment: Technically speaking Windows doesn't use file extensions either, it's just that Windows 95's file manager kept using the last characters of the filename to determine file type after breaking out of the MS-DOS naming scheme and the convention has since remained.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`perl`'s `rename` (as typically found on Debian where it's also called `prename`), or [this derivative](https://metacpan.org/source/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/README) (`rename` package on Debian):

```
rename 's/\.tif$//' *.tif
```

`util-linux` `rename` (as typically found on Red Hat, `rename.ul` on Debian):

```
rename -- .tif '' *.tif
```

<sub>(note that that one would rename `blah.tiffany.tif` to `blahfany.tif`)</sub>

Comment: I believe the "Debian" rename is by Larry Wall (comes with Perl?) and "Red Hat" one is from util-linux (rename.ul in Debian IIRC).

Comment: @XTL: True. I just call them that because they're the "rename" programs found in Debian or Red Hat derivatives.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I never realized that there were different versions of 'rename'.  I assume there are other subtle differences between the commands in debian & redhat.  I'll have to lookup some of their differences.

Comment: The second command resulted invalid syntax, but first one worked.

Answer (score 16):

For a non-rename, you might do:

```
$ for i in *.tif; do mv -i $i `basename $i .tif`; done
```

(-i to warn against replacing a file)

Comment: Safer faster version: `for i in ./*.tif; do mv -i "$i" "${i%.tif}"; done`

Comment: @jw013 your comment should be a top-level answer.

Comment: @jw013 Why `./*.tif` instead of `*.tif`?

Comment: @PedroA `./` is a pretty safe prefix to prevent file names from being misinterpreted, for example a file beginning with `-` may be interpreted as option. [Example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/9537)

Comment: I went with the anwer from jw013, though I wanted to skip warnings for replacing (as that was my intention) so I've switched `-i` to `-f` (CentOS 6) to force overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

If you use IBM AIX you won't have a `rename` command, so in order to batch remove file extensions you'll have to use plain vanilla System V UNIX commands:

```
for file in *.tif; do
   mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/.tif$//'`;
done;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rename -- .oldext .newext *.oldext
```

This substitutes the old extension with the new one. To simply remove the extension you can explicitly pass in an empty string as an argument.

```
rename -- .gz.tmp  '' *.gz.tmp
```

With the above command all files with `.gz.tmp` extension in the current folder will be renamed to `filename.gz`.

Refer to the article : [Linux: remove file extensions for multiple files](http://assortedtechnotes.blogspot.com/2015/05/linux-remove-file-extensions-for.html)  for details.

Comment: That assumes the util-linux implementation of `rename` which is incompatible with (and much more limited than) the traditional `rename` command from `perl`.

Comment: Also note that it replaces the _first_ occurrence of `.oldext` within the file name, not necessarily the extension (`foo.oldextasy.oldext` would be renamed to `footasy.oldext`).

Answer (score 1):

```
perl-rename 's/\.tif//' *.tif
```

Use `-n` for dry run.

Comment: This is a duplicate of an answer posted 9 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

A non rename method.

```
ls | grep .tif | xargs -I % sh -c 'mv % $(basename % .tif)'
```

Answer (score -2):

can we make this recursive

```
for i in *.gz; do mv -i $i `basename $i .gz`; done
```