# Extract name of file without extension in shell script

Tags: programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to remove file extension from a string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18765/best-way-to-remove-file-extension-from-a-string)
>   [How to rename multiple files by removing the extension?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34549/how-to-rename-multiple-files-by-removing-the-extension)

I have a metric boatload of .txt files I'd like to load into a database.

The tables have the same name as the .txt files, but without the extension.

So I'd like to execute the command

```
for f in *.txt; do mysql -u root -p -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$f' INTO TABLE $f" -D rn4; done
```

However, the last `$f` is giving me headaches as I want it to only use the name, not the extension.

So for the file `piRNA.txt` the command would look like

```
mysql -u root -p -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'piRNA.txt' INTO TABLE piRNA" -D rn4
```

How do I do this?

To make the answer useful for others, please do not just give me the command, but please write a line or two about how to extract the name in the general case.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but it seems to contain the answer. Did not know about the 'basename' command. Will keep this question as other people wondering about the same thing are unlikely to find that thread by any reasonable search.

Comment: Parameter expansion would work bettter in your case, IMO. Also, it's a duplicate if the answer is the same, irrespective of how you ask the question ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this in a shell script:

```
f=piRNA.txt
g=${f%.txt}
```

Executing

```
 echo $f $g
```

yields following output:

```
piRNA.txt piRNA
```

With that `%` syntax you remove a matching suffix patttern. The suffix pattern in the example is `.txt` and `f` is the variable it is removed from. Note that a pattern may also contain wildcards (cf. e.g. the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for details).

As always, in case your filenames may contain spaces you have to put the references of variables into double quotes (e.g. `"$f"` etc.).

Comment: 20 seconds before you ;) But I'll accept yours if you explain what that command does. Pretty please?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat, no problem, is this explanation sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo ${f%.*};done
```

- Using [pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) `*.txt` to match all files end with `.txt`
- `${f%.*}` is shell syntax for [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), remove the smallest suffix matched pattern in `$f`. Here we remove the extension part `.txt`.