# Linux Rename File Beginning with "--"

Tags: linux, command, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus)

This is an awkward one, I have received some files from a windows machine which have been named things like

```
"----index.html"
```

When I try to grep hello * in a directory containing these files I get grep errors and when I try to mv ----index.html index.html there are similar errors:

```
mv: unrecognized option '----index.html'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mv -- ----index.html index.html
grep hello -- *
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `--` before the arguments for your `mv` command.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use:

```
mv ./----index.html index.html
```