# deal with file names with "-" as beginning on linux

Tags: linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus)

I'm using linux
I have some files with file names like

```
-0fdlfld
-xfifd
```

I want to delete them using shell "rm"
but it doesn't work

are there anyways to deal with such file names?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -- -0fdlfld
rm -- -xfifd
```

Should do it.