# How to use commands on files that start with "-"

Tags: shell-script

I'm having trouble using using commands on files that start with "-" (i.e. -file 1, -file 2). It is giving me invalid option errors.

For example:

```
cp '-file 1' '-file 2'
```

However, echo still works.

```
echo "Hello World" > '-file 2'
```

How can I make it so that the "-" does not signify that I'm choosing an option?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/80216)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most POSIX utilities specify that `--` can be used to terminate option arguments:

```
cp -- '-file 1' '-file 2'
```

You can also reference the current directory using the `.` hard link to the current directory:

```
cp './-file 1' './-file 2'
```

Comment: A third option: the leading hyphen isn't mistaken for the beginning of an option if the word is expected as the argument to a preceding option. For example: in `grep -e -foo file.txt`, the `-e` option takes an argument, so `grep`  doesn't expect `-foo` to be an option.