# How to remove a file that start with ">" or other unusual characters

Tags: files, rm

I've accidentally created a file called

```
> option[value='2016']
```

How can I delete it?

```
My attempts:

$ rm "> option[value='2016']"
rm: cannot remove ‘> option[value='2016']’: No such file or directory
$ rm \> o*
rm: cannot remove ‘>’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘o*’: No such file or directory
$ rm `> o*`                                                                               
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
$ rm \> option*
rm: cannot remove ‘>’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘option*’: No such file or directory
$ rm '\> option*'                                                                         
rm: cannot remove ‘\\> option*’: No such file or directory
$
$ rm "\> option*"                                                                         
rm: cannot remove ‘\\> option*’: No such file or directory
```

File listing:

```
HAPPY_PLUS_OPTIONS/
o*
op*
> option[value='2016']
> option[value='ALFA ROMEO']
README.md
rspec_conversions/
.rubocop.yml
SAD/
SAD_PLUS_OPTIONS/
```

Comment: Have you tried using wild cards? rm \*option\*

Comment: The following question looks ridiculously, but **did you try GUI file managers?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a file whose name begins with "-" (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

another option

```
ls -i
```

which give (with proper inode value)

```
5233 > option[value='2016']   5689 foo
```

then

```
find . -inum 5233 -delete
```

optionnaly (to preview)

```
find . -inum 5233 -print
```

you can also add `-xdev` if there is another filesystem beneath .

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the "--" option which according to man:

```
 The rm command uses getopt(3) to parse its arguments, which allows it to
 accept the `--' option which will cause it to stop processing flag options at
 that point.  This will allow the removal of file names that begin with a dash
 (`-').  For example:
       rm -- -filename
```

So I tried:

```
touch -- "> option[value='2016']"
```

And removed it with:

```
rm -- "> option[value='2016']"
```

Easiest way to check if the filename was correctly entered:

```
rm -- ">[tab]
```

And let auto-complete do the job.

PS: As tempting as it sounds, don't create a file name "-rf *". Bad things may happen.

```
-rw-r--r--    1 stephan  staff      0 Sep 13 14:11 -rf *
```

Always use "-i" to be safe.

```
iMac:~ stephan$ rm -i -- "-rf *"
remove -rf *? Y
```

Comment: This by far the best answer, by far.

Answer (score 8):

The initial problem was a leading space, thus

```
rm " > option[value='2016']"
    ^ here
```

works.

Updated the question to be about files starting with > etc.

Answer (score 3):

For an interactive approach (often safer):

If there are some special named files in current directory.

You can use `rm ./` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to list files and then you can select the file and delete it.

Comment: Enter `Tab` twice to find files.

Answer (score 1):

For `rm`, there's nothing magical about `>`. You only need to make sure the angle bracket gets to it (=prevent the shell from interpretting it as a redirection).

```
> "> option[value='2016']"  #create it
rm "> option[value='2016']" #remove it

#remove all files in the current directory that have > in them
rm -- {,.}*\>*
```

If you're on a sensible modern system, you should be able to get properly escaped names with tab completion.