# How to use `find` command with a directory starting with special characters

Tags: shell-script, shell, find

I am writing a script which takes a directory name from user, then `find` files inside it. The script may fail if the user use some special characters with their directory name.

```
$ var="-foobar";
$ find "$var";
find: unknown predicate `-foobar'
```

For a lot of commands, it is easy to avoid the problem by giving `--` to indicate that it is an end of options. But it does not with with `find`:

```
$ find -- "$var";
find: unknown predicate `-foobar'
```

What should I do to handle directory with unpredictable characters?

Comment: See the [*second* answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1529/73093).

Comment: Since I don't know the path given by the user will be relative (`-foobar`) or absolute (`/tmp/-foobar`), just preceeding it with `./` is not safe. I guess the solution to handle this would be: `find $(realpath -- "$var")`.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Formally `--` does work to indicate the end of *options*. Compare `find -L .` and `find -- -L .` POSIX defines `-H` and `-L` as options, nothing more. Implementations may add few options, but still paths and expression are not options.

Comment: Your solution with `realpath` won't help if you want relative paths to stay relative. I mean you may want `find` to print/use `-foobar/baz` or `./-foobar/baz`, not `/home/livy/-foobar/baz`. I can imagine scenarios where this matters. Consider `find "$(printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed '1 s|^-|./-|')"`.

Comment: What OS are you using here?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I'm using Ubuntu server. What are the scenarios you are talking about? I am not familiar with `sed` command and don't understand it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to reproduce your issue. @KamilMaciorowski was the one who mentioned sed.

Comment: Scenarios? E.g. you may want to use the results in the context of another (semi-mirrored) directory; like find some files here, delete corresponding files there. Or use the results with `tar` without full paths ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18681595/10765659)). About `sed`: `sed '1 s|^-|./-|'` will replace `-` at the very beginning of the first line with `./-`. Input without leading `-` is unaffected. The "first line" condition may seem excessive but note a name like `-a\n-b` (where `\n` denotes the newline character) is a valid name in general. You don't want to alter the second line.