# How to create a file with a name that starts with the symbol '-'

Tags: terminal

I want to use the `touch` command in linux terminal in order to create a file with a name that begins with the symbol `-`, say `-attempt`.

How can I overcome the the fact that `-` is a special character?

For example, if I wanted to create a file with the name `#attempt`, I couldnt just write `touch #attempt`

Instead I would have to write `touch \#attempt`, but in the `-` case even if I use `\` it still does not work well).

Comment: See [How do I delete a file whose name begins with "-" (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus/1529#1529)

Comment: BTW, having a filename beginning with `-` leads to difficulty working with it, unless that's your intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

Move the `-`away from the first character

```
touch ./-foo
```

Or use the `--` end-of-switches marker

```
touch -- -foo
```

Answer (score 3):

`touch \#attempt` works because the hash sign is special to the shell. Similarly, you'd need something like `touch \(foo\)`, or `touch 'this & that'` for filenames with parenthesis or ampersands etc.

But escaping the dash does not help since it's not special *to the shell*, but to the utility launched by the shell. Running the shell command line `touch \-foo` is just the same as running `touch -foo`, `touch` will get the single argument `-foo` anyway.

So, instead of escaping, something else is required.

The standard way to tell a program to stop interpreting command arguments as (possible) options, is to insert the argument `--` after the options. E.g. this would run `rm` with the option `-f`, on a file called `-r`:

```
rm -f -- -r
```

(and `rm -- --` would remove a file called `--`.)

Alternatively, you can work around the issue by making sure the dash is not the first character of the filename, usually by prepending `./`. So again, this would remove a file called `-rf`:

```
rm ./-rf
```